# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo in android camera app

Tags: java, android, camera

i m trying to make custom android app from android Developer site with android studio but my app doesnt run in emulator its shows error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Here is My Main Activity

```
    package firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;



import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


/**
 * Created by Varun on 12/24/14.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

    private Camera mcamera;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mcamera = getcam();
        cam mcam = new cam(this, mcamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camPre);
        preview.addView(mcam);


    }

    public static Camera getcam() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return c;
    }

    private Camera.PictureCallback mpicturecallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile=getOutPutMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile==null){
                android.util.Log.d("Error","Problem");
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };



          //CREATE A FILE URI FOR SAVING AN IMAGE OR VIDEO
            private static Uri getOutPutMediaFileUri(int type){
            return Uri.fromFile(getOutPutMediaFile(type));

            }
    private static File getOutPutMediaFile(int type){

        File mediaStorage=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"MyCameraApp");

        if (!mediaStorage.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorage.mkdirs()) {
                android.util.Log.d("Mycamera", "Failed Error");
                return null;
            }
        }

        File mediaName;

        if (type==MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaName = new File(mediaStorage.getPath()+File.separator+"Rim_"+".jpg");
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }


        return mediaName;
    }

    //Button Listener to the capture button
    Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Capture);
    public void clickPic(View view){
        mcamera.takePicture(null,null,mpicturecallback);
    }
}
```

And camera preview activity

```
    package firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;


public class cam extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder mholder;
    private Camera mcamera;

    public cam(Context context,Camera camera){
        super(context);
        mholder=getHolder();
        mholder.addCallback(this);
        mholder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }


    /**
     * This is called immediately after the surface is first created.
     * Implementations of this should start up whatever rendering code
     * they desire.  Note that only one thread can ever draw into
     * a {@link android.view.Surface}, so you should not draw into the Surface here
     * if your normal rendering will be in another thread.
     *
     * @param holder The SurfaceHolder whose surface is being created.
     */
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        try {
            mcamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mcamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    /**
     * This is called immediately after any structural changes (format or
     * size) have been made to the surface.  You should at this point update
     * the imagery in the surface.  This method is always called at least
     * once, after {@link #surfaceCreated}.
     *
     * @param holder The SurfaceHolder whose surface has changed.
     * @param format The new PixelFormat of the surface.
     * @param width  The new width of the surface.
     * @param height The new height of the surface.
     */
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (mholder.getSurface()==null) {
            return;
        }
        mcamera.stopPreview();

        //Start Preview WIth New Setting
        try {
            mcamera.setPreviewDisplay(mholder);
            mcamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * This is called immediately before a surface is being destroyed. After
     * returning from this call, you should no longer try to access this
     * surface.  If you have a rendering thread that directly accesses
     * the surface, you must ensure that thread is no longer touching the
     * Surface before returning from this function.
     *
     * @param holder The SurfaceHolder whose surface is being destroyed.
     */
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        if (mholder.getSurface()!=null){
            mholder.getSurface().release();
            mcamera=null;
        }
    }
}
```

This Is Manifest file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" ></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.write_external_storage"></uses-permission>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" android:required="false">
         </uses-feature>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera" android:required="false"></uses-feature>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                >


                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
                    </action>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">

                    </category>

                </intent-filter>
                </activity>


        </application>

    </manifest>
```

And Here Is Complete LogCat From Android Studio

```
  12-26 15:26:46.284      610-610/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
    12-26 15:26:48.244      610-615/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    12-26 15:26:48.434      610-615/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    12-26 15:26:48.683      610-615/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    12-26 15:26:48.754      610-610/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    12-26 15:26:48.754      610-610/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
    12-26 15:26:48.786      610-615/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    12-26 15:26:48.822      610-610/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
                at firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:102)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-26 15:26:49.154      610-615/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    12-26 15:26:49.234      610-615/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    12-26 15:26:49.654      610-615/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    12-26 15:26:49.734      610-615/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    12-26 15:27:18.314      610-610/firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 610 SIG: 9
```

> i dont understand from where its throwing RuntimeException

at this line it says in error log
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
says it return null its button id in xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/camPre"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/click"
            android:text="Capture"

            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />


        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i tried to debug app but still can get why its throwing null pointer exception 
it can be because of button id or this line according to error log line no 102
in main activity

```
if (!mediaStorage.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorage.mkdirs()) {
            android.util.Log.d("Mycamera", "Failed Error");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at your stack trace, you missed all the important parts such as the actual exception and where it occurred. _Runtime_ is just a type of exception.

Comment: What's line MainActivity.java:102?

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ File mediaName;

        if (type==MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaName = new File(mediaStorage.getPath()+File.separator+"Rim_"+".jpg");
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }


        return mediaName;
    }
Line Above return mediaName is 102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
>   at firstapp.boysjoys.com.waste.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:102)
> ```

You're calling `findViewById()` too early, in activity `<init>` phase that includes e.g. member variable initialization.

You can only call activity methods like `findViewById()` in `onCreate()` or later in the activity lifecycle.

Move the `findViewById()` call to `onCreate()` to get rid of the NPE. Put it after `setContentView()` so that it can actually return a non-null value.